# Pigpio won't initialise when used by a script started by a service even with root privilege

Tags: gpio, pi-4, raspbian-buster, pigpio, systemd-startup

**Problem:**
I'm writing a Homebridge plugin that needs access to the Pi's GPIO.

This plugin uses the pigpio javascript wrapper (https://github.com/fivdi/pigpio) of the pigpio C library (https://github.com/joan2937/pigpio), which requires root privilege. I need those libraries to send waveforms through the GPIO.

When I run `sudo homebridge`, everything works fine.

However when **Homebridge runs as a service** `sudo hb-service start`, I get this error:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------+
|Sorry, you don't have permission to run this program.    |
|Try running as root, e.g. precede the command with sudo. |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

Which comes from the pigpio C library (https://github.com/joan2937/pigpio/blob/v75/pigpio.c#L7287-L7296) and more precisely from this piece of code:

```
fdMem = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR | O_SYNC)
```

Even if I set the user of the homebridge service (in `/etc/systemd/system/homebridge.service`) as root:

```
[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
Group=root
```

And I check that the related processes (hb-service starts the homebridge process) are effectively owned by root:

```
$ ps -u -p 1843
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root      1843  0.5  3.3 155148 66880 ?        Ssl  15:20   0:08 hb-service
```

```
$ ps -u -p 1857
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root      1857  0.1  2.0 129844 40720 ?        Sl   15:20   0:03 homebridge
```

And /dev/mem has normal rights:

```
$ ls -l /dev/mem
crw-r----- 1 root kmem 1, 1 Apr 27 20:17 /dev/mem
```

**What i've tried:**

- Let any user read and write in /dev/mem: `sudo chmod 666 /dev/mem`: same error
- Add homebridge and pi users to the kmem group and let the kmem group read and write in /dev/mem: `sudo usermod -aG kmem pi`, `sudo usermod -aG kmem homebridge`, `sudo chmod g+rw /dev/mem`: same error

**Environment:**

- Raspberry Pi 4 B
- Raspbian Buster Lite fully upgraded headless
- Node.js Version: v12.16.2
- NPM Version: 6.14.4
- Homebridge version: 1.0.2

The error only occurs when the script is started by the service. And even if the service has root privilege, it doesn't work. I have no idea what can cause this?


Any help is welcome!


**Edited 2020-04-29 13:12 CEST:**

- Result of `systemctl cat homebridge.service`:

```
# /etc/systemd/system/homebridge.service
[Unit]
Description=Homebridge
Wants=network-online.target
After=syslog.target network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
Group=root
PermissionsStartOnly=true
WorkingDirectory=/var/lib/homebridge
EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/homebridge
ExecStartPre=-run-parts /etc/hb-service/homebridge/prestart.d
ExecStartPre=-/usr/lib/node_modules/homebridge-config-ui-x/dist/bin/hb-service.js before-start $HOMEBRIDGE_OPTS
ExecStart=/usr/lib/node_modules/homebridge-config-ui-x/dist/bin/hb-service.js run $HOMEBRIDGE_OPTS
Restart=always
RestartSec=3
KillMode=process
CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_IPC_LOCK CAP_NET_ADMIN CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE CAP_NET_RAW CAP_SETGID CAP_SETUID CAP_SYS_CHROOT CAP_CHOWN CAP_FOWNER CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE CAP_AUDIT_WRITE CAP_SYS_ADMIN
AmbientCapabilities=CAP_NET_RAW CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

- Result of `systemctl status homebridge.service`:

```
● homebridge.service - Homebridge
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/homebridge.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2020-04-28 16:16:39 BST; 19h ago
  Process: 7928 ExecStartPre=/bin/run-parts /etc/hb-service/homebridge/prestart.d (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 7931 ExecStartPre=/usr/lib/node_modules/homebridge-config-ui-x/dist/bin/hb-service.js before-start $HOMEBRIDGE_OPTS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 7938 (hb-service)
    Tasks: 22 (limit: 4035)
   Memory: 94.7M
   CGroup: /system.slice/homebridge.service
           ├─7938 hb-service
           └─9107 homebridge

Apr 28 16:16:39 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Homebridge...
Apr 28 16:16:39 raspberrypi run-parts[7928]: Ensuring /var/lib/homebridge is owned by root
Apr 28 16:16:39 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Homebridge.
Apr 28 16:16:39 raspberrypi hb-service.js[7938]: [4/28/2020, 16:16:39] [HB Supervisor] Homebridge Storage Path: /var/lib/homebridge
Apr 28 16:16:39 raspberrypi hb-service.js[7938]: [4/28/2020, 16:16:39] [HB Supervisor] Homebridge Config Path: /var/lib/homebridge/config.json
Apr 28 16:16:39 raspberrypi hb-service.js[7938]: [4/28/2020, 16:16:39] [HB Supervisor] Logging to /var/lib/homebridge/homebridge.log
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the output of these commands to it: `systemctl cat homebridge.service` and `systemctl status homebridge.service`.

Comment: @Ingo Question edited with the result of the commands. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot follow your specific issue because lack of detailed information about your programs, setup and environment. But I will discuss the additional output you have given. I may not exactly match what you need but it could give you an idea where to look to solve your problem.

In general, **systemd** can start any service that you can successfully run on the commandline. The first step is, to do just that and explore what environment is needed. From `systemctl status homebridge.service` there cannot be seen any failing of the service. The service itself is active (running) and all pre executed programs have successful finished (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS). So executing on the commandline should also do:

```
rpi ~$ sudo /bin/run-parts /etc/hb-service/homebridge/prestart.d
rpi ~$ sudo /bin/bash -c 'source /etc/default/homebridge && /usr/lib/node_modules/homebridge-config-ui-x/dist/bin/hb-service.js before-start $HOMEBRIDGE_OPTS'
rpi ~$ sudo /bin/bash -c 'source /etc/default/homebridge && /usr/lib/node_modules/homebridge-config-ui-x/dist/bin/hb-service.js run $HOMEBRIDGE_OPTS'
```

There is an info message from `run-parts`:

```
Apr 28 16:16:39 raspberrypi run-parts[7928]: Ensuring /var/lib/homebridge is owned by root
```

This has nothing to do with executing as root. Just check the ownerchip with

```
rpi ~$ ls -l /var/lib/homebridge
```

and if not set to `root`, I would set it (chown).

It seems that `hb-service.js` does not respect to log to the default systemd journal and uses its own log file:

```
Apr 28 16:16:39 raspberrypi hb-service.js[7938]: [4/28/2020, 16:16:39] [HB Supervisor] Logging to /var/lib/homebridge/homebridge.log
```

You should have a look at it.

**Now lets have a look at the systemd Unit:**

```
Type=simple
User=root
Group=root
```

are not needed. That is the default setting.

```
PermissionsStartOnly=true
```

This is a real issue because [PermissionsStartOnly is deprecated](https://superuser.com/questions/1504114/permissionsstartonly-alternative-in-systemd). You will not find any documentation about it on Raspbian Buster. The [old documentation of PermissionsStartOnly](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/53852) says:

> Takes a boolean argument. If true, the permission-related execution options, as configured with User= and similar options (see systemd.exec(5) for more information), are only applied to the process started with ExecStart=, and not to the various other ExecStartPre=, ExecStartPost=, ExecReload=, ExecStop=, and ExecStopPost= commands. If false, the setting is applied to all configured commands the same way. Defaults to false.

Because you don't have a restricted `User=` and `Group=` setting (other than root) for `ExecStart=` this option isn't needed for my understanding.

```
ExecStartPre=-run-parts /etc/hb-service/homebridge/prestart.d
ExecStartPre=-/usr/lib/node_modules/homebridge-config-ui-x/dist/bin/hb-service.js before-start $HOMEBRIDGE_OPTS
```

You should use the full path `/bin/run-parts`. Both options are prefixed with **`-`**. This changes errors only to warnings and the service will not fail. But I think the preconditions are needed to successful start the main program. So I would not suppress errors and omit the dash.

```
Restart=always
RestartSec=3
```

A failing service should not always Restart. It never helps to fix a buggy service.

```
CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_IPC_LOCK CAP_NET_ADMIN CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE CAP_NET_RAW CAP_SETGID CAP_SETUID CAP_SYS_CHROOT CAP_CHOWN CAP_FOWNER CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE CAP_AUDIT_WRITE CAP_SYS_ADMIN
AmbientCapabilities=CAP_NET_RAW CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE
```

These are sophisticated systemd internal settings. For my experience it is better to let systemd do such things so I would not use it. If you are unsure you can look with:

```
rpi ~$ systemctl show homebridge.service
```

when the service is running and compare what options are set.

So I would start with this Unit file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Homebridge
Wants=network-online.target
After=syslog.target network-online.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/lib/homebridge
EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/homebridge
ExecStartPre=/bin/run-parts /etc/hb-service/homebridge/prestart.d
ExecStartPre=/usr/lib/node_modules/homebridge-config-ui-x/dist/bin/hb-service.js before-start $HOMEBRIDGE_OPTS
ExecStart=/usr/lib/node_modules/homebridge-config-ui-x/dist/bin/hb-service.js run $HOMEBRIDGE_OPTS
# Maybe better to use default KillMode=control-group? Then comment next line.
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This should give you more information what fails and you can modify it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and help! Your proposed Unit file did it without any further modification. I was stuck on this problem for a long time, and your answer was very helpful! I will take the time to check if I need to do other changes thanks all this information, but so far the plugin is working well.

Comment: Nice :-) Haven't expected it on the first run. From the status I just see that there in the CGroup are running two programs: `7938 hb-service` and `9107 homebridge`. I think when stopping the service, both programs shall stop, not only the main program. So try with a deleted (commented) line `KillMode=process`, so KillMode=control-group will work by default. Default settings are mostly the best.